# Azure Devops Build Pipeline - Click Once Application Release Versioning Strategy

Tags: git, azure-devops, clickonce, versioning

A new test version gets published when someone is pushing in the dev branch. Now the developer has to specify the publish version manually and the minimum required version is automatically set to the published version - so an update of the click once application is being forced.

Ideally the developer should not need to specify the publish version since it should be a rolling release and always be one version number later than the last release. I could write a Powershell Script that checks for the latest release and increments the version number in the build pipeline - so we have an incremental build. But this has the drawback that the published version number is not checked in the source control system.

How can I approach this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this has the drawback that the published version number is not
>   checked in the source control system. How can I approach this issue?

The publish version of clickonce application is controlled by `ApplicationRevision` and `ApplicationVersion` properties defined in `xx.csproj`.

In Azure devops service, we always specify the publish version by passing new values to msbuild arguments using [Global Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019#global-properties) way. But this won't change the real definitions in project file:

```
  <ApplicationRevision>xxx</ApplicationRevision>
  <ApplicationVersion>xxx</ApplicationVersion>
```

Since we're specifying the publish version this way, it's hard to add the publish version into source control system.

**As an alternative workaround:**

You may consider specifying the version with azure devops predefined variables. For me, I use the format of build number like this:

[image]

Then I pass the `$(Build.BuildNumber)` as the `ApplicationRevision` property. So now I have one increasing publish version. And I can check the pipeline history to know in which run(and corresponding commit) I have the successful publish:

[image]

Since we're specifying the version with a temporary value in command-line, so far we're not able to add a temporary value into source control.